# Find total count of success and failed records

Tags: sql, database

I have to formulate SQL Query to display total success and failed device processing.
Suppose User selects 2 devices and runs some process.
Each Process which user triggers will spawn 4 jobs (1 devices has 2 jobs to run). Since here user select 2 devices so 4 records comes in db. Now based on ParentTaskId I need to display total successfull,failed jobs with total devices.

We count a job on a device as success only when both jobs(Type 1,Type 2) are success.

Note : If jobtype 1 fails , jobtype 2 will not trigger

```
Ex:

Case 1:
ParentTaskId    DeviceId    TaskType    TaskStatus
101             a123         1          Success
101             a123         1          Success
101             a124         2          Success
101             a124         2          Success

Output : 
ParentTaskId    Success     Failed      TotalDevices
101              2           0              2

Case 2:
ParentTaskId    DeviceId    TaskType    TaskStatus
101             a123         1          Success
101             a123         1          Success
101             a124         2          Failed
101             a124         2          Success

Output:
ParentTaskId    Success     Failed      TotalDevices
101              1           1              2
```

Tried below approach but no success:

```
select
ParentTaskId,
COUNT(DISTINCT(DeviceId)),
count( case when TaskStatus='SUCCESS' then 1 end) as Success,
count( case when TaskStatus!='SUCCESS' then 1 end) as Failed
from XYZ 
where ParentTaskId = '101'
group by ParentTaskId,DeviceId
```

Any pointers/suggestions on this ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT DeviceId)`, to make code clearer.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `group by ParentTaskId` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation -- the inner one to get the status per parent and device.  For this, you can actually use `min(taskStatus)` to get the status:

```
select ParentTaskId,
       sum(case when taskStatus = 'Success' then 1 else 0 end) as success,
       sum(case when taskStatus = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) as failed,
       count(*) as total
from (select ParentTaskId, deviceId, min(taskStatus) as taskStatus
      from t
      group by ParentTaskId, deviceId
     ) pd
group by ParentTaskId;
```